# Automatic Clustering in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, clustering

Given a set of random data points on a map, I would like to cluster the data points based on number of data points in a cluster, time to travel within all the data points in the cluster,and/or number of clusters needed. Is there a way or extension in ArcGIS Desktop that can automatically create the cluster?

Answer (score 2):

Without more details in your Question, it is difficult to be certain of your precise requirements.  However, I think your best starting point may to review the help page entitled **[An overview of the Mapping Clusters toolset](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005p0000000w000000)**:

> The Mapping Clusters tools perform cluster analysis to identify the
>   locations of statistically significant hot spots, cold spots, spatial
>   outliers, and similar features.

You may also want to review **[How to find Clusters of N Points Within X Distance?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6787/how-to-find-clusters-of-n-points-within-x-distance)**